# Android MediaRecorder prepared failed -1

Tags: java, android, camera, ioexception, prepare

First of all, I've checked stackoverflow again an again about this problem and I'm still not able to find out what's wrong ... I try to record a video, without audio, and I still have this prepared failed -1 issue ... The file is created but stays at 0kb.
I tried different output format, check my manifest etc ... Can't find the problem :(

More info => I test my app on a Galaxy S2 android 2.3.5 ...

Any help more than appreciated ...

Thanks !

Here is my CameraView activity, where I display the preview and record the vidéo ( preview works fine ):

```
package com.guillaimej.testapplication.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraInputView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraInputView";

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    int w, h;

    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    public CameraInputView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        // FETCH THE CAMERA INSTANCE
        mCamera = camera;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Find screen size
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();


        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13){
            w = display.getWidth();
            h = display.getHeight();
                Point point = new Point();
                display.getSize(point);
                w = point.x;
                h = point.y;
        }else{
            w = display.getWidth();
            h = display.getHeight();
        }

        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(params.getSupportedPreviewSizes(),w,h);
        params.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

        params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
        if (params.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder); : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // SET PREVIEW DISPLAY
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // INIT THE MEDIA RECORDER
        initMediaRecorder();

    }

    public boolean startRecording(){
        try {
            mediaRecorder.start();
            return true;

        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error IllegalStateException in startRecording(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean stopRecording(){
        try {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            return true;
        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error IllegalStateException in stopRecording(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean initMediaRecorder(){
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Camera recording

        try {

            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);



            String mFileName =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String outputFile = mFileName + "/default.mp4";
            Log.i(TAG, "File Path is: " + outputFile);

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);

            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, " Error IllegalStateException in initMediaRecorder():" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error IllegalStateException in prepareMediaRecorder(): " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error IOException in prepareMediaRecorder(): " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    public Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h){
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(mediaRecorder != null){
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout for this activity :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.guillaimej.testapplication.app.CameraInputActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_layout"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">


</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/record_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:max="5"
        />

</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:id="@+id/button_layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:background="@drawable/record"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/domygif"
        android:background="@drawable/flask"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/swap_cam"
        android:background="@drawable/swap"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"/>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guillaimej.testapplication.app" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListOfFileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_of_file" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_input" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CustomImageGallery"
            android:label="@string/cutom_gallery_title" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GIFeditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gifedit" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And finally, here is what I get in the logcat:

```
06-29 12:51:03.910  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 74K, 48% free 2821K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 58ms
06-29 12:51:04.015  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app D/CLIPBOARD﹕ Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-29 12:51:07.735  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Display.getSize, referenced from method com.guillaimej.testapplication.app.CameraInputView.<init>
06-29 12:51:07.735  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7585: Landroid/view/Display;.getSize (Landroid/graphics/Point;)V
06-29 12:51:07.735  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002e
06-29 12:51:07.735  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0031-0038 in Lcom/guillaimej/testapplication/app/CameraInputView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/hardware/Camera;)V
06-29 12:51:07.820  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/Surface﹕ Surface::init token -2 identity 979
06-29 12:51:07.825  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/MediaRecorder﹕ prepare failed: -1
06-29 12:51:07.825  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/CameraInputView﹕ Error IOException in prepareMediaRecorder(): prepare failed.
06-29 12:51:15.135  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/MediaRecorder﹕ start called in an invalid state: 0
06-29 12:51:15.135  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/CameraInputView﹕ Error IllegalStateException in startRecording(): null
06-29 12:51:19.695  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/MediaRecorder﹕ stop called in an invalid state: 0
06-29 12:51:19.695  14280-14280/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app E/CameraInputView﹕ Error IllegalStateException in stopRecording(): null
06-29 12:51:19.705  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ java.lang.InterruptedException
06-29 12:51:19.705  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
06-29 12:51:19.705  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1213)
06-29 12:51:19.710  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1195)
06-29 12:51:19.710  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at com.guillaimej.testapplication.app.CameraInputActivity$RecordBarTask.doInBackground(CameraInputActivity.java:188)
06-29 12:51:19.715  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at com.guillaimej.testapplication.app.CameraInputActivity$RecordBarTask.doInBackground(CameraInputActivity.java:175)
06-29 12:51:19.715  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-29 12:51:19.715  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-29 12:51:19.715  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-29 12:51:19.720  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-29 12:51:19.720  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-29 12:51:19.720  14280-14441/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: is there a `mediaRecorder.prepare()` before `start()`?

Comment: oh it is, in `SurfaceCreated()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just not follow the order mentioned here: [Capturing Videos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video)

Comment: Thanks, I've tired to match the right order, I think ... but still no luck ! But i've noticed something weird in my logcat, I don't know if that changes something tho :

06-29 14:12:17.665  19128-19128/com.guillaimej.testapplication.app D/Camera﹕ app passed NULL surface